# Get the difference of several arrays that are inside other arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following json from which I read the data:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "brand":"Mike",
    "cycle": "C1",
    "sides": {
      "1": {"sideName":"A",
          "active": false},
      "2": {"sideName":"B",
          "active": false},
      "3": {"sideName":"C",
          "active": true}
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "brand":"Luis",
    "cycle": "C2",
    "sides": {
      "1": {"sideName":"A",
          "active": false},
      "2": {"sideName":"B",
          "active": false},
      "3": {"sideName":"C",
          "active": true},
      "4": {"sideName":"D",
          "active": true}
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "brand":"Lucas",
    "cycle": "Z1",
    "sides": {
      "1": {"sideName":"H",
          "active": false},
      "2": {"sideName":"U",
          "active": false},
      "3": {"sideName":"L",
          "active": true},
      "4": {"sideName":"A",
          "active": true}
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "brand":"Edd",
    "cycle": "R1",
    "sides": {
      "1": {"sideName":"A",
          "active": false},
      "2": {"sideName":"B",
          "active": false},
      "3": {"sideName":"C",
          "active": true},
      "4": {"sideName":"Q",
          "active": true}
    }
  }
]
```

I need to keep an array containing all the common 'sidenames' without repeating them.
I'm using react jsx but a pure js solution would work for me.
Example:

**result = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "H", "U", "L", "Q"]**

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far and we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Set` for this. A set is a collection of unique items:

```js
const items = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "brand":"Mike",
    "cycle": "C1",
    "sides": {
      "1": {"sideName":"A",
          "active": false},
      "2": {"sideName":"B",
          "active": false},
      "3": {"sideName":"C",
          "active": true}
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "brand":"Luis",
    "cycle": "C2",
    "sides": {
      "1": {"sideName":"A",
          "active": false},
      "2": {"sideName":"B",
          "active": false},
      "3": {"sideName":"C",
          "active": true},
      "4": {"sideName":"D",
          "active": true}
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "brand":"Lucas",
    "cycle": "Z1",
    "sides": {
      "1": {"sideName":"H",
          "active": false},
      "2": {"sideName":"U",
          "active": false},
      "3": {"sideName":"L",
          "active": true},
      "4": {"sideName":"A",
          "active": true}
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "brand":"Edd",
    "cycle": "R1",
    "sides": {
      "1": {"sideName":"A",
          "active": false},
      "2": {"sideName":"B",
          "active": false},
      "3": {"sideName":"C",
          "active": true},
      "4": {"sideName":"Q",
          "active": true}
    }
  }
]

const uniqueSideNames = new Set();

for (const item of items) {
  for (const side of Object.values(item.sides)) {
    uniqueSideNames.add(side.sideName);
  }
}

console.log([...uniqueSideNames]);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to first reduce your list to just the items that you need and `flatMap` them to be one flattened array.

`items.flatMap(item => Object.values(item.sides).map(side => side.sideName))`

This will give you a flattened list of *all* `sideNames` including duplicates.

A `Set` datastructure is a data structure that only allows unique items, so adding all of these items to a set and then converting them back to an array will dedupe for you.

That might look like:

```
Array.from(new Set(items.flatMap(item => 
  Object.values(item.sides)
        .map(side => side.sideName)))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

After differentiating objects by their `sideName`, you can use [new Set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#remove_duplicate_elements_from_an_array) to create a new array that is cleaned of the duplicated values.

```js
const items = [{"id": 1, "brand":"Mike", "cycle": "C1", "sides": {"1": {"sideName":"A", "active": false}, "2": {"sideName":"B","active": false},"3": {"sideName":"C","active": true}}}, {"id": 2,"brand":"Luis", "cycle": "C2","sides": {"1": {"sideName":"A","active": false},"2": {"sideName":"B","active": false},"3": {"sideName":"C","active": true},"4": {"sideName":"D","active": true}}},{"id": 3,"brand":"Lucas","cycle": "Z1","sides": {"1": {"sideName":"H","active": false},"2": {"sideName":"U","active": false},"3": {"sideName":"L","active": true},"4": {"sideName":"A","active": true}}},{"id": 4,"brand":"Edd","cycle": "R1","sides": {"1": {"sideName":"A","active": false},"2": {"sideName":"B","active": false},"3": {"sideName":"C","active": true},"4": {"sideName":"Q","active": true}}}];

const mappedItems = [...new Set(items.flatMap(({ sides })=> Object.values(sides)).map(({ sideName })=> sideName))];

console.log("Output:", mappedItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [{
    "id": 1,
    "brand": "Mike",
    "cycle": "C1",
    "sides": {
      "1": {
        "sideName": "A",
        "active": false
      },
      "2": {
        "sideName": "B",
        "active": false
      },
      "3": {
        "sideName": "C",
        "active": true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "brand": "Luis",
    "cycle": "C2",
    "sides": {
      "1": {
        "sideName": "A",
        "active": false
      },
      "2": {
        "sideName": "B",
        "active": false
      },
      "3": {
        "sideName": "C",
        "active": true
      },
      "4": {
        "sideName": "D",
        "active": true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "brand": "Lucas",
    "cycle": "Z1",
    "sides": {
      "1": {
        "sideName": "H",
        "active": false
      },
      "2": {
        "sideName": "U",
        "active": false
      },
      "3": {
        "sideName": "L",
        "active": true
      },
      "4": {
        "sideName": "A",
        "active": true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "brand": "Edd",
    "cycle": "R1",
    "sides": {
      "1": {
        "sideName": "A",
        "active": false
      },
      "2": {
        "sideName": "B",
        "active": false
      },
      "3": {
        "sideName": "C",
        "active": true
      },
      "4": {
        "sideName": "Q",
        "active": true
      }
    }
  }
]

const result = []

arr.forEach(({
  sides
}) => {
  for (const key in sides) {
    if (!result.includes(sides[key].sideName)) result.push(sides[key].sideName)
  }
})

console.log(result)
```